# Making a referral reward system using reactJS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, referrals

I am trying to create a referral system using reactJS and firebase dynamic links but is genuinely confused on using the dynamic links part. The firebase documentation says it support swift, Java and Kotlin but my app is a webapp running on a browser. How can I make use of referral rewards in my react app?
The link to the documentation:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/use-cases/rewarded-referral

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the web you don't need Firebase Dynamic Links, but you'd instead use regular hyperlinks to [build a link to a specific page in your app that you want to apply the reward on](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/use-cases/rewarded-referral#create_invitation_links) and to then [parse the information from the link on that page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/use-cases/rewarded-referral#retrieve_referral_information_in_your_app).

The rest of the approach (such as the [Cloud Function awarding the reward](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/use-cases/rewarded-referral#grant_rewards_to_the_referrer_and_the_recipient)) in the documentation you linked should still work the same.

If you're having trouble getting it to work for your use-case, it's most likely we can help when you post a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of where you are stuck.